# gmap3 Marker getPosition() doesnt work

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

i´m using gmap3 plugin for jquery and use 'get' to get a specific marker, i do get the right marker, as i can access `marker.data` i defined as i init the map, but how do i get the position of the marker to let the map zoom to this position inside the callback function

```
$('#map').gmap3({
    get: {
        name:"marker",
        tag:"${i}",
        full:true,
        callback: function(marker){
            var center = marker.getPosition();
            $('#getdistance').gmap3({
                map:{
                    center:center,
                    options:{
                        zoom:17,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        scrollwheel: true,
                        streetViewControl: true
                    }
                }
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

trying so throws error :

```
 marker.getPosition is not a function
```

so anyone has an idea ?

thanks in advance for ***any*** hint

Comment: With gmap3, do objects not have properties as opposed to raw Google Maps' methods? Try `marker.position` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#map').gmap3({
    marker: {// change get to marker
        name:"marker",
        tag:"${i}",
        full:true,
        callback: function(marker){
            var center = marker.getPosition();
            $('#getdistance').gmap3({
                map:{
                    center:center,
                    options:{
                        zoom:17,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        scrollwheel: true,
                        streetViewControl: true
                    }
                }
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

Test here http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getaddress-49

Comment: yeah that works nice, but i cant acces marker.data anymore it´s undefined now, but whatever i mark this as solution